# How do I create a table using 'CASE' query?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I run a query as below, then it works well.

```
Select USER_ID, case
when AGECD >= 10 and AGECD <= 19 then 1
when AGECD >= 20 and AGECD <= 24 then 2
when AGECD >= 25 and AGECD <= 29 then 2.5
when AGECD >= 30 and AGECD <= 34 then 3
when AGECD >= 35 and AGECD <= 39 then 3.5
when AGECD >= 40 and AGECD <= 44 then 4
when AGECD >= 45 and AGECD <= 49 then 4.5
when AGECD >= 50 and AGECD <= 54 then 5
when AGECD >= 55 and AGECD <= 59 then 5.5
when AGECD >= 60 and AGECD <= 69 then 6
when AGECD >= 70 and AGECD <= 100 then 7
else 0
END as AGETYPE
from table_name;
```

I want to create a new table with the above result.

So I typed the following query:

```
create table AGETYPE as
    Select USER_ID, case
    when AGECD >= 10 and AGECD <= 19 then 1
    when AGECD >= 20 and AGECD <= 24 then 2
    when AGECD >= 25 and AGECD <= 29 then 2.5
    when AGECD >= 30 and AGECD <= 34 then 3
    when AGECD >= 35 and AGECD <= 39 then 3.5
    when AGECD >= 40 and AGECD <= 44 then 4
    when AGECD >= 45 and AGECD <= 49 then 4.5
    when AGECD >= 50 and AGECD <= 54 then 5
    when AGECD >= 55 and AGECD <= 59 then 5.5
    when AGECD >= 60 and AGECD <= 69 then 6
    when AGECD >= 70 and AGECD <= 100 then 7
    else 0
    END as AGETYPE
    from table_name;
```

However, error appears and it says the cause is "The specified number was invalid".

I am using oracle sql developer, and I think I must use some appropriate 'tabs' in my code to make it work right. How do I fix it?

Comment: why is my post downvoted?

Comment: @LukStorms It still does not work. When I tried to save the above query result as a csv file, the error message "The specified number was invalide" still appears

Comment: So I think there is nothing wrong with the first coding, but there is something wrong when “creating the above result as a table”.

Comment: What is a datatype of `AGECD` column ? I guess that it is VARCHAR but not number, and this column contains some values which cannot be converted to numbers.

Comment: Please include the `CREATE TABLE ...` statement (the DDL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't post your table structure. My guess there's something you're not saying about it that creates some issue. Anyway, I assumed some table structure and tried it here locally.

It worked like a charm! Here it is:

```
create table table_name (
  user_id number(6),
  agecd number(6)
);

insert into table_name (user_id, agecd) values (1, 15);
insert into table_name (user_id, agecd) values (2, 16);
insert into table_name (user_id, agecd) values (3, 35);

create table agetype as 
Select USER_ID, case
when AGECD >= 10 and AGECD <= 19 then 1
when AGECD >= 20 and AGECD <= 24 then 2
when AGECD >= 25 and AGECD <= 29 then 2.5
when AGECD >= 30 and AGECD <= 34 then 3
when AGECD >= 35 and AGECD <= 39 then 3.5
when AGECD >= 40 and AGECD <= 44 then 4
when AGECD >= 45 and AGECD <= 49 then 4.5
when AGECD >= 50 and AGECD <= 54 then 5
when AGECD >= 55 and AGECD <= 59 then 5.5
when AGECD >= 60 and AGECD <= 69 then 6
when AGECD >= 70 and AGECD <= 100 then 7
else 0
END as AGETYPE
from table_name;
```

So, what's the difference with your case?

Answer (score -1):

create table <>
as Select COMCSNO, 
case when <> then <> else NULL -- here or use 'NULL' 
if you want to store string literal END as AGETYPE from table_name

Comment: I tried it but this does not work with the same error message

Comment: Refernce link with detail

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21968952/Creating-table-with-Case-statement-in-Oracle-9i.html